# Copying the Last Column of different sheets, and then combine into one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

First of All, sorry for my poor English and computer skill. 
Im workin on a excel for taking attendance of some school teams(>50). 
Each team has its own sheet to take attendance. 
Each team have differnt training date and number. 
I am trying to put all the data from different sheets into one,and I made it. 
But the problem is that I want to check the attendance of the teams which had training the day before. Because of the different training date and numbers, the attendance record of different team appear on different columns. I;m just trying to ask all of the team insert a new column in a specific place for taking attendance. But I wish I can use the "Lastcolumn" or other methods to solve this stupid situtaion.

My Stupid Solution:
1,combine all sheet
2,clear all the data except the most updated one 
3,filter "ABS" 
4,choose the team whcih have training yesterday by human

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Range("A1").Select

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 2
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Select
        lastrow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        Range("A" & (lastrow + 1)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
'
'
    Columns("F:BB").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A4:E4").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$E$37").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="ABS"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could paste the format that the attendance sheets are in that would help us answer your question. However it seems like this solution could possibly work.

replace the lines

```
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

in your code with

```
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Assuming that All the Cells in row A have a value to the column you want to copy.

Comment: GREAT ! Thx Mike. But I also want to copy the first few columns (the member name and grade etc) to the summary sheet, thats why there are "Range("A4:E4").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter" in my script. is it possible to copy the first few and the last column in once ?

Comment: See my other answer which addresses your comment! @Rdi Lau

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can select two ranges at the same time using the Range Object.

Insert at the top of your code;

```
Dim rng1, rng2, rngCombo As Range
```

Then modify so;

```
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set rng1 = Selection
Set rng2 = Range("A4:E4")
Set rngCombo = Union(rng1, rng2)
rngCombo.Select
```

Hope this helped! 
If it did a vote up would be much appreciated!